# How to take info from a JSON and separate the wanted info?

Tags: javascript, json

so I have the following json for example.

```
{
"BTC": {
    "available": 0.00024868,
    "onOrder": 0,
    "btcValue": 0.00024868,
    "btcTotal": 0.00024868
},
"LTC": {
    "available": 0,
    "onOrder": 0,
    "btcValue": 0,
    "btcTotal": 0
},
"ETH": {
    "available": 0,
    "onOrder": 0,
    "btcValue": 0,
    "btcTotal": 0
},
"NEO": {
    "available": 0,
    "onOrder": 0,
    "btcValue": 0,
    "btcTotal": 0
},
"BNB": {
    "available": 0.08943066,
    "onOrder": 0,
    "btcValue": 0.0004663808919,
    "btcTotal": 0.0004663808919
}
```

}

I need to remove the items that don't have a value in the "available" field (such as NEO and ETH and set the result in an array. Then remove the onOrder and btcTotal fields.

such as:

BTC 0.00024868 0.00024868

BNB 0.8943066 0.0004663808919

I am writing my little project in JS on NodeJS as a little hobby project.
But, so far all I am able to get right is listing the JSON in the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [editing a JSON in JS and putting it in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587929/editing-a-json-in-js-and-putting-it-in-an-array)